# What's the name ahead of an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm curious about what's the name ahead of a javascript object.

e.g. 
for a jQuery event object I get

```
f.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", timeStamp: 447797.25500000006, jQuery1720986234321818227: true, isDefaultPrevented: function…}
```

for a Backbone Model object I get

```
child {cid: "c2", attributes: Object, _changing: false, _previousAttributes: Object, changed: Object…}
```

for my own build object I get

```
Object {a: 123}
```

What're the meaning of **f.Event**, **child** and **Object**? (Since when I use typeof to test these they are all return "object".) Can I modify these names with my own?

Comment: What are you displaying these objects with? A browser console?

Comment: @4castle Yes with a chrome console.